# power shell executing git command throws error

Tags: git, powershell

while executing simple command through powershell i m getting error as below

git : fatal: Not a valid object name USER/TS00102/BAS0204_test
At M:\work\Azure_experiment\ListBranches.ps1:47 char:1

- git ls-tree -r $Branch

please find my code below

```
InitialiseGIT
#ListBranches
$Branch="USER/TS00102/BAS0204_test"
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
git branch --show-current
git ls-tree -r $Branch`
```

Very first function initialising git correctly and i m getting current branch as USER/TS00102/BAS0204_test . But while passing the branch via variable it throws error.

Any help would be highly apprecicated

Comment: It seems the branch `USER/TS00102/BAS0204_test` does not exist. Is it printed in `git branch`?

Comment: the branch exist and its shows by executing command git branch --show-current